# Javascript always add 1 to total rows

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am confused about this Javascript code which I used to get total rows in a table. It will always output an excess of 1. Example: it will print 5 instead of 4!

```
<script>
    (function() {
       var div = document.getElementById('divID11');
       div.innerHTML =  document.getElementById('tableId11').rows.length;
    })();
</script>

<div id =divID11></div>
```

and table structure is shown below

```
<table id="tableId11>
 <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>
   </th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td><?php echo $data ?></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
```

What I am lacking here?

[image]

Outputs 3 for the name column when in fact there only 2.

Comment: are you counting the rows in the THEAD?

Comment: your code working fine for me ... [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pJ86u/)

Comment: @Thilo, I'm counting td inside tbody

Comment: As you are counting total rows inside the table, your code is working fine.

Comment: *"I'm counting td inside tbody"* -- not in the code you've posted here at least. It's counting all rows, including those in the thead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want count only `TBODY` rows, use this JavaScript code:

```
(function() {
    var div = document.getElementById('divID11');
    div.innerHTML =  document.getElementById('tableId11').getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0].rows.length;
})();
```

Your JavaScript code counting all rows in table (thead and tbody). If you want count only tbody rows, you must specify the element (so you must modify your code to specify, with which part of your table you wanna work).

**[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/pJ86u/3/)**

Comment: your suggestion works for me.Now I know what went wrong on my Javascript

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 var div = document.getElementById('divID11');
        div.innerHTML = document.getElementById('tableId1').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].rows.length;
```